# Problem with installing.bash file on Ubuntu Linux 23.04

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to execute the install.bash code on my Linux terminal. Here are the steps I've taken:

```bash
thal@thal-11T30037GE:/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/doc$ sudo chmod +x install.bash
thal@thal-11T30037GE:/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/doc$ sudo ./install.bash install
```

and it gave me the following output with errors:

```
Creating virtual python environment
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualenv
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,982 B of archives.
After this operation, 13.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 virtualenv all 20.19.0+ds-1 [1,982 B]
Fetched 1,982 B in 1s (1,355 B/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package virtualenv.
(Reading database ... 218593 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualenv_20.19.0+ds-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualenv (20.19.0+ds-1) ...
Setting up thal-labelprinting (1.1.0) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Config import LabelsConfig, PrinterConfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config'
dpkg: error processing package thal-labelprinting (--configure):
 installed thal-labelprinting package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up virtualenv (20.19.0+ds-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 thal-labelprinting
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR!
```

It seems like there are issues with missing modules and package configurations. I suspect the `Config` module might be improperly configured or missing.

Here's a snippet from my `install.bash` script where it sets up the environment:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 install"
        exit 2
fi

function run()  {
local cmd=$1
echo $cmd
$cmd >> /dev/null 2>&1 || {
        echo "ERROR!"
        exit 1
        }
}

function check() {
        test $? -eq "0" || {
                echo "ERROR!"
                exit 1
        }
}

uid=`id -u`
test $uid -eq "0" || {
        echo "Must be root!"
        exit 1
}

echo ""
echo "Creating virtual python environment"
apt-get install -y virtualenv
check
run "mkdir -p /opt/usr/virtualenv"
run "virtualenv -p python3 /opt/usr/virtualenv/labelprinting"
#run "rm /opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/lib/python3.6/no-global-site-packages.txt"

echo ""
echo "Installing python packages"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install wxPython==4.0.6"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install elaphe3==0.2.0"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install reportlab==3.5.23"

echo "Creating labelprinting logrotate configuration"
echo "/var/log/labelprinting/*/*.log {
        rotate 31
        compress
        missingok
        maxsize=10M
        daily
        notifempty
        copytruncate
}" > /etc/logrotate.d/labelprinting
check

echo "#PDF Cleanup Cronjob" >> /etc/crontab
echo "0 */4 * * * root find /data/labelprinting/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;" >> /etc/crontab
echo "" >> /etc/crontab


echo ""
echo "Finished successfully!"
exit 0
```

after installing `install.bash` running it on terminal

Based on the output you provided, there are two distinct errors:

The first error is related to the Python script `/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py` which is encountering a `ModuleNotFoundError`. It's unable to find a module named `Config`. This suggests that there might be a missing or improperly configured dependency.

Comment: Please re-check the Ubuntu version. I doubt you already have next year's version. Please [edit] your question and details what software you are trying to install. Pleasee always copy&paste error messages with enough context. Where does the text "Based on the output you provided..." come from. Did you copy&paste everything instead of re-typing? `/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/` vs. `/opt/usr/thales_labelprinting/` looks suspicious. And you seem to have omitted the script name from the code block with the error message.

Comment: hello i have changed the question and have pasted the output error, sorry i am relatively new to this

Comment: it is a third party software, i have all the necessary files from them and it works on the another ubuntu perfectly and i am migrating now to other computer, so in my short research i am trying this at the moment

Comment: Whoops.  That would do it.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: From the identifiers `LabelsConfig, PrinterConfig` in the error message `File "/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py", line 7, in <module>` `from Config import LabelsConfig, PrinterConfig` I guess the module should be part of the software you are trying to install. The script `/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py` seems to be part of the package `thal-labelprinting (1.1.0)`. Check if this package or one of its dependencies contains a Python module `Config`.  Add links to a product page and/or to a software download page if possible.

Comment: i wont be able to share the links to product as it is customised for us. it does contain Config.py in /opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/lib if thats what you mean?

Comment: could you please help me out i am still struggling